# How to index Dynamic url page

Tags: seo, indexing

I have a site that look like this:

```
Main page (index.php)
```

where a user can research a business.

To display result at page `(search/index.php)`, the page url will look something like this:

```
/search/index.php?what=plumber&where=montreal&page=1
```

The page will generate dynamic link to access the business profile found. When you click on one of those links, you get here:

```
/entreprises/index.php?companyName=Something
```

How can I get the previous link to be indexed on `Google`?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a good situation for the canonical URL tag. You'll want to specify a single URL for the page in question, and then other variations of that url getting to the same page (i.e. searches, tags, etc.) will refer to the stated canonical url as the actual url for SEO purposes.

Google has a detailed description of the tag here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en